# RestKit 0.20 - Mapping with keyPath

Tags: ios, restkit, restkit-0.20

This is my response body:

```
{
  "bsqn": 5,
  "results": [
    {
      "sqn": 1,
      "res": "oldu!"
    }
  ]
}
```

I wanna get through for "res" property which i really need, by using this keyPath:"bsqn.res"

```
//TestResponse.h
@interface TestResponse : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *res;

+ (RKObjectMapping *)objectMapping;

@end

// TestResponse.m
@implementation TestResponse

+ (RKObjectMapping *)objectMapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"res": @"res"}];

    return mapping;
}

@end


RKResponseDescriptor *newDesc = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:    
[TestResponse objectMapping] method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"bsqn.res"     
statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

But it gives this error:

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key hashcode
```

Is there a way to do what i want? Thanks..

Comment: `RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];` I _think_ `[self class]` should be changed to `self` since you are calling this in class method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON, `bsqn.res` doesn't exist. `bsqn` is just a string.

Change your response descriptor to `keyPath:@"results"` and RestKit will map each item in the results array into a new instance of your `TestResponse` and set the `res` property.